# Python call multiple functions in parallel and combine result

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have to write a job to perform difference type of analysis on given document. I know I can do sequentially i.e., call each parser one by one. 
A very high level script structure is given below

```
def summarize(doc):
    pass
def LengthCount(doc):
    pass
def LanguageFinder(doc):
    pass
def ProfanityFinder(doc):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = "Some document"
    smry = summarize(doc)
    length = LengthCount(doc)
    lang = LanguageFinder(doc)
    profanity = ProfanityFinder(doc)

    # Save sumary, length, language, profanity information in database
```

But for performance improvement, I think these task can be run in parallel. How can I do it. What are the possible ways for this purpose in Python especially 3.x version. It is quite possible that one parser (module) take more time than other but overall if they could be run in parallel they it will increase performance. Lastly, if not possible in Python, any other language is also welcome.

Comment: what are your current timing rate for the current approach? what should be clarified is "how does **doc** accessed/used in each function" ?

Comment: Its streaming data from some public platform and number of documents vary from 10k to 1000k per second. We are more concerned with parallelism and not with data and modules take too much time due to their rigorous activities. We cannot optimize module up til a specific level.

Comment: as you've written that you are dealing with *10k to 1000k per second* - instead of parallelizing your functions - parallelize processing of documents (one process per doc)

Answer (score 0):

In Python you have a few options for concurrency/parallelism. There is the `threading` module which allows you to execute code in multiple logical threads and the `multiprocessing` module which allows you to spawn multiple processes. There is also the `concurrent.futures` module that provides an API into both of these mechanisms.

If your process is CPU-bound (i.e. you are running at 100% of the CPU available to Python throughout - note this is not 100% CPU if you have a multi-core or hyper-threading machine) you are unlikely to see much benefit from threading as this doesn't actually use multiple CPU threads in parallel, it just allows one to take over from another whilst the first is waiting for IO. Multiprocessing is likely to be more useful for you as this allows you to run using multiple CPU threads. You can start each of your functions in its own process using the Process class:

```
import multiprocessing

#function defs here 

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=LengthCount, args=(doc,))
p.start()
# repeat for other processes
```

You will need to tweak your code to have the functions return to a shared variable (or write straight to your database) rather than directly return your result so you can access them once the process is complete.